# How to set a div (custom Radio-Button and Checkbox) as required?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create custom and accessible Radio- and Checkbox-Buttons and found the nice solution of W3C, using divs and aria role="radio".

https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/NOTE-wai-aria-practices-1.1-20171214/examples/radio/radio-1/radio-1.html

```
<div role="radiogroup" aria-labelledby="group_label_1" id="rg1">
   <h3 id="group_label_1">Label</h3>
   <div role="radio" aria-checked="false" tabindex="0">
   Button
   </div>
</div>
```

It looks and works great for me, but I want to implement Radio-Buttons as required fields of the form. Problem: in this solution is no input-element and for this reason no required-attribute possible..

Answer (score 0):

The WAI-ARIA aria-required property indicates that user input is required before submission. The aria-required property can have values of "true" or "false". For example, if a user must fill in an field, then aria-required is set to "true".

```
<div role="radiogroup" aria-labelledby="group_label_1" aria-required="true"  id="rg1">
   <h3 id="group_label_1">Label</h3>
   <div role="radio" aria-checked="false" tabindex="0">
   Button
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you only make it require with add a property

```
aria-checked = true
```

into first any radio.

ex:

```
<div role="radiogroup" aria-labelledby="group_label_1" id="rg1">
   <h3 id="group_label_1">Label</h3>
   <div role="radio" aria-checked="true" tabindex="0">
   Button
   </div>

   <h3 id="group_label_2">Label2</h3>
   <div role="radio" aria-checked="false" tabindex="1">
   Button2
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: its checked but not required

Answer (score 0):

Check [W3school custom radio button](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_custom_radio) for creating custom radio buttons. and you can put required attribute to radio buttons check the following code for the demo.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
/* The container */
.container {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 35px;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 22px;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

/* Hide the browser's default radio button */
.container input {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* Create a custom radio button */
.checkmark {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    background-color: #eee;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

/* On mouse-over, add a grey background color */
.container:hover input ~ .checkmark {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

/* When the radio button is checked, add a blue background */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark {
    background-color: #2196F3;
}

/* Create the indicator (the dot/circle - hidden when not checked) */
.checkmark:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}

/* Show the indicator (dot/circle) when checked */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
    display: block;
}

/* Style the indicator (dot/circle) */
.container .checkmark:after {
    top: 9px;
    left: 9px;
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: white;
}
</style>
<body>

<h1>Custom Radio Buttons</h1>
<form method="post" action="https://facebook.com" target="_blank">
<label class="container">One
  <input type="radio"  required="" name="radio">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container">Two
  <input type="radio" name="radio" required="">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>

<input type="submit" value="asd" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why are you using divs any reason?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add the `required` tag to your input elements.

Here's a working CodePen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zWzaKM